# Can I post on page's wall with an iOS application?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-page

How to post to a page's wall using FaceBook Graph API for iPhone?

Should I need to prompt for any permission for that?

Is it possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using the [Post method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). It requires the `publish_stream` permission. The user needs to have "liked" the page in question.

> To publish a wall post, POST the
>   message and optional attachment to the
>   feed/wall of the user, page or group,
>   i.e.,
>   http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed.

Annoyingly, the one thing that Graph API will not allow, is to let the user "like" a page through it. The user must already have "liked" the page. (catch-22)

[Graph API Page documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Comment: Thank you @dredful, PROFILE_ID = page id true?

Comment: @yogs: Yes, PROFILE_ID = page id

Comment: Is this still possible?

Comment: @OzairKafray, I am afraid I haven't looked at the Facebook SDK for quite some time. I cannot answer your question. Sorry.