# Using facebook SDK to post in group, possible?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have searched all over but cannot find the answer to my question.

Is it possible to post messages from an iOS app into a facebook group instead of the normal timeline using the facebook SDK in Xcode.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803110/can-i-post-on-pages-wall-with-help-of-facebook-ios-sdk-graph-api-in-iphone-appl